# Remove dynamic TextBox'es on CheckedListBox SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkboxlist

When I checked the CheckBoxList Items the dynamic texboxes are added. But on Unchecked I want to remove particular textboxes. The code is working fine for adding textboxes but gives me exception at removing.Any Help will be great.

My Code:

```
 iy = 0;
 private void checkedListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (load == false)
        {
            return;
        }
            PackingDetails pd = new PackingDetails();
            var txt = new TextBox();
            for (iy = 0; iy < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; iy++)
            if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(iy))
            {



                    txt.Name = iy.ToString();
                    txt.Text = iy.ToString();
                    txt.Location = new Point(23, 32 + (iy * 28));
                    txt.Visible = true;
                    this.Controls.Add(txt);
                    break;

            }

            else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(iy) == CheckState.Unchecked)
            {
                foreach (TextBox t in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (t.Name == iy.ToString())
```

// here if i skip this if condition the topmost textbox but not the clicked one is deleted.

```
                    {
                        this.Controls.Remove(t);
                        t.Dispose();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                break;
            }
    }
```

OR

I have also tried this

```
  int iy = 0;
    private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
       TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = VerticalScroll.Minimum;
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            txt.Name = iy.ToString();
            txt.Text = iy.ToString();
            txt.Location = new Point(23, 32 + (iy * 28));
            txt.Visible = true;
            this.Controls.Add(txt);
            count = iy;
            iy++;

        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
            {
                if (control is TextBox)
                {
                   // here it deletes the topmost textbox but not the clicked one. Here if I used if condition like control.Name == iy.ToString() Nothing happens
                        this.Controls.Remove(control);
                        control.Dispose();
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide specific exception messages.

Comment: Invalid CastException   Details is Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.

Comment: Where does this error occur?

Comment: @manraj Don't go all commanding on us. We are here trying to help you for free. It actually costs us time to help, so the least you can do is be friendly to the community.

Comment: i have update the question. Its not also working on checkedListBox1_ItemCheck.

Answer (score 0):

this.Controls will have multiple control:

```
 else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(iy) == CheckState.Unchecked)
        {
            foreach (Control con in this.Controls)
            {
                if(con is TextBox)
                {
                    if (t.Name == iy.ToString())
                    {
                      this.Controls.Remove(t);
                      t.Dispose();
                      break;
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        }
```

Also, If it doesn't work, debug your code and see how the control is flowing

Comment: Can you debug your code and check if control is flowing to :  this.Controls.Remove(t); or not.

Comment: i doubt if threestate for checkedListBox1 is set to true and its state might be Intermediate and not the unchecked one..

Comment: yes dear. t.Name is null when the breakpoint goes to inner loop. Sort me why it is happening if the control is adding successfully through name

Comment: I have update the code on item check.Can you update this one

Answer (score 0):

Set `CheckOnClick` to `True` of `CheckBoxList` ..

```
    private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (iy = 0; iy < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; iy++)
        {
            var item = checkedListBox1.Items[iy];
            string ctlName = item.ToString();
            Control txt = null;
            if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(iy))
            {
                txt = FindControl(ctlName);
                if (txt != null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                txt = new TextBox();
                txt.Name = ctlName;
                txt.Text = ctlName;
                txt.Location = new Point(150, 32 + (iy * 28));
                txt.Visible = true;
                this.Controls.Add(txt);                    
            }
            else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(iy) == CheckState.Unchecked)
            {
                txt = FindControl(ctlName);
                if (txt==null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                this.Controls.Remove(txt);
                txt.Dispose();                    
            }
        }


    }

    Control FindControl(String ctlName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this.Controls[i].Name==ctlName)
            {
                return this.Controls[i];
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: dear its c# code. Not asp.net

Comment: It's also c# :P .. Ok i got you .. you are working on `WinForms` .. Look on my update in minutes ..

Comment: Please check the changes ..

Comment: dear its not working. I have update the code on item check.Can you update this one

Comment: It's working fine no exception!!! ... Can you please specify .. what's `not working`...

Comment: it add controls after clicking two or more checkboxes. and return Syste. Data.Row

Comment: checkboxlist have values from the db

Comment: Solved dear .. check it :) .. Set `CheckOnClick` to `True` of `CheckListBox`

Comment: dear it add only one textbox if i check both checkboxlist then it will not work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've guessed the right origin of the error:

```
 foreach (TextBox t in this.Controls)
 {
       if (t.Name == iy.ToString())
       {
            this.Controls.Remove(t);
            t.Dispose();
            break;
       }
 }
```

Could *possibly* work, but can also *possibly* fail. One cannot just assume all `Controls` in `this.Controls` are of the type `TextBox`. Note that `this.Controls` will return all `Controls` in a specific context (`this`).

The solution is to check whether its a `TextBox` or not:

```
    foreach (var control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            if (t.Name != null && t.Name == iy.ToString())
            {
                this.Controls.Remove(t);
                t.Dispose();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not very constructive.. WHERE does it fail?

Comment: it says t.Name is null

Comment: I have update the code on item check.Can you update this one plz

Comment: The way you are using now is a very bad practice. Did you try the code I've supplied? This should work.

Comment: yes dear. I have used but not get any solution

Comment: I understand, but what does go wrong? Simply saying 'it doesn't work' doesn't help anyone at all..

Comment: if (t.Name != null && t.Name == iy.ToString())  here it always check iy = 2

Comment: I assume that is because of `checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(iy)`. Although that's a whole other question as your main question was fixing the error, this newly question is about the flow of your code not being correct.

Comment: dear can you update this on item checked.It delete the topmost textbox but not the clicked textbox