# c# datagridview row width automatically increases on scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

My Datagridview contains DateTimeColumn which overlaps the another next row column on scrolling. I had set the DatagridView properties like

AutoSizeColumnsMode : Fill

AutoSizeRowsMode: AllCellsExceptheaders

AllowUserstoAddRows: True

But it show me following result. Any Help will be great

[image]

My Code

```
  private void dataGridView4_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.RowIndex != -1)
            {
                if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 || e.ColumnIndex == 2)
                {

                    oDateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();


                    dataGridView4.Controls.Add(oDateTimePicker);


                    oDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;


                    Rectangle oRectangle = dataGridView4.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);


                    oDateTimePicker.Size = new Size(oRectangle.Width, oRectangle.Height);


                    oDateTimePicker.Location = new Point(oRectangle.X, oRectangle.Y);
                    oDateTimePicker.TextChanged += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker_OnTextChange);
                    oDateTimePicker.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());
        }
    }



    private void dateTimePicker_OnTextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView4.CurrentCell.Value = oDateTimePicker.Text.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: How is your `DateTimeColumn` implemented? It seems instead of a real `DataGridViewColumn` you are aligning some `DateTimePicker` above the `DataGridView`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I had edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems instead of a using real `DataGridViewColumn` you are aligning some `DateTimePicker` above the `DataGridView`.

Instead on aligning some `DateTimePicker` controls above your `DataGridView` you should create a custom `DataGridViewColumn`.

Here is a good [MSDN Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) that implements a `CalendarColumn`.

Comment: how to make column 2 to CalendarColumn

Comment: The same way you make 2 column `TextBoxColumn`, It's the standard way of creating custom columns. You can use it in designer or by code.

Comment: It's strongly recommended to use such approach but if for learning purpose or some reason else, you want to layout some controls above the grid, yo may find may answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32281605/3110834) helpful.

Comment: Can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751178/remove-dynamic-textboxes-on-checkedlistbox-selectedindexchanged

Comment: @manraj Unfortunately the question is closed and I can't post an answer, but the main idea is **-** When you click an item, add a text box to a flow layout panel, and set the textbox's tag property to index of checked item. Then when unchecking an item, you can simply find the textbox based on its tag and remove it.

Comment: @manraj check the link again. It seems it's an answered question.

Comment: Please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348440/how-to-bring-database-online-in-my-online-site